# Inserting an integer from C# to MySQL

Tags: mysql-workbench

I am getting this error when i try to insert from C# to MySQL
I tried using a BIGINT but it didn't work

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Out of range value for column 'S_num' at row 1

[image: MySQL error]

Comment: You didn't provide any code, just the error, how are we supposed to help you then?

Comment: Please include the code you use to fill in your value, and also possibly the schema of your table.

Comment: string Query = "insert into best_database.Test1(P_code,S_num,H_version,Date_created) values('" + this.txtPrCode.Text+ "','" + Convert.ToInt64(this.scnS_Number.Text) + "','" + this.txtHVers.Text + "','" + this.txtDCreat.Text + "');";

Comment: on my schema the scnS_number is a BIGINT data type

Comment: I want to store a number which is 16 char long

Answer (score 0):

The value of the C# int is either to big or to small for BIGINT too handle.(probably to big)

BIGINT in mysql directly translates into c#s Int64(or long).

Hope this post helps.

Comment: i am using Int64 on C# and BIGINT on mysql i want to store a value this big "9999999999999999"

Comment: Try to run the value of the string "query" in mysql workbench. And see what happens.

If S_num is indeed a bigint this code should work (if the value is about 16 chars long)